How to specify destination of CreateExportJobRequest in AWS SES VDM?
I am trying to follow https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/vdm-dashboard.html#vdm-dashboard-export-message-cli . Specifically it says: "These examples show you how to use the CreateExportJob operation to search and find particular messages you've sent, see their current delivery and engagement status, and export the results of your search to a .csv or .json file using the AWS CLI. This is the same data used in the Virtual Deliverability Manager dashboard's Messages table.".
I have the following code:
        String s3Url = "s3://my-bucket-name/export-files/";
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        CreateExportJobRequest request = CreateExportJobRequest.builder()
                .exportDataSource(
                        ExportDataSource.builder()
                                .messageInsightsDataSource(
                                        MessageInsightsDataSource.builder()
                                                .startDate(now.minus(7, ChronoUnit.DAYS))
                                                .endDate(now)
                                                .include(
                                                        MessageInsightsFilters.builder()
                                                                .destination("myname@mydestination.com")
                                                                .build()
                                                )
                                                .build()
                                )
                                .build()
                )
                .exportDestination(
                        ExportDestination.builder()
                                .dataFormat(DataFormat.JSON)
                                .s3Url(s3Url)
                                .build()
                )
                .build();

But I am getting an error "software.amazon.awssdk.services.sesv2.model.BadRequestException: Providing a custom S3 URL is not supported (Service: SesV2, Status Code: 400, Request ID: XX-YY-ZZ)"
But how else can I specify the destination S3 bucket? Is there some other way I am supposed to generate the url? Or is that specified elsewhere?

Although not the best documented, the key is to use a ListExportJobsRequest listExportJobsRequest and then use the id from that for a GetExportJobRequest getExportJobRequest. The GetExportJobResponse will have the download url link.
